# What causes XYY Syndrome?

Tags: genetics

It's obvious how a misdisjunction can result in klinefelter's syndrome (XXY) but I don't see how this can result in XYY syndrome. Your parents have a collective total of only one Y chromosome so how can any misdisjunction result in a child with two Y chromosomes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from a Y nondisjunction in the father. Anaphase nondisjunction of the Y yields a YY, which goes with one X from the mother to give XYY.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYY_syndrome#Cause  during sperm generation